# Size of Object in Go

Tags: go

Just thinking of building an LRU based caching mechanism which is memory consumption aware as I can't find a ready one after some searching. The cached item is native Go object which can be basic type, struct, slice, array or any valid combination, but without recursive reference, and we can assign a upper limited of memory usage to the pool and once the total memory consumption reach a threshold, a cleanup based on Latest Recently Used would be triggered.

I understand accurate memory size calculation is not practical but I think a rough estimation may do lot help here. At least it's better then item number counting like what's done in GroupCache ignoring size of the cached object.

So what's a proper way to calculate/estimate the bytes used by given value?

Comment: Do you know beforehand the exact layout all types of the things going into that cache, or is the structure only know at runtime? If you know all different layouts you could calc the size of each of them and then run counters for the amount of each type in cache.

Comment: Could you use [runtime.ReadMemStats](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#ReadMemStats) for a top down approach?

Comment: @RickyA now since it could be allocated on the stack and it won't show there.

Comment: @OneOfOne: True, but if you use one big struct to hold all items the likelyhood of them on the stack are fairly low. According to [this](https://golang.org/doc/faq#stack_or_heap) go seems to favor heap anyway when in doubt of var scope. And since we are not looking for an exact number this reflection stuff seems like a huge overhead here.

Comment: Oh, and btw goroutine stacks are implemented [*on the heap*](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#goroutines)

Comment: @RickyA you learn something new every day!

Comment: @Ricky thanks for the ideas :) but as a in-process caching it's not easy to use a top down way because the memory is shared with the application, and objects are not in one size... it's also possible to use a separate process and use top down way but there would be IPC overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote this function a long time ago, it's recursive and haven't been tested much, but it gives you an idea on how to implement it:

```
var (
    sliceSize  = uint64(reflect.TypeOf(reflect.SliceHeader{}).Size())
    stringSize = uint64(reflect.TypeOf(reflect.StringHeader{}).Size())
)

func isNativeType(k reflect.Kind) bool {
    switch k {
    case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64,
        reflect.Uint, reflect.Uint8, reflect.Uint16, reflect.Uint32, reflect.Uint64,
        reflect.Float32, reflect.Float64, reflect.Complex64, reflect.Complex128:
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func sizeofInternal(val reflect.Value, fromStruct bool, depth int) (sz uint64) {
    if depth++; depth > 1000 {
        panic("sizeOf recursed more than 1000 times.")
    }

    typ := val.Type()

    if !fromStruct {
        sz = uint64(typ.Size())
    }

    switch val.Kind() {
    case reflect.Ptr:
        if val.IsNil() {
            break
        }
        sz += sizeofInternal(val.Elem(), false, depth)

    case reflect.Struct:
        for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
            sz += sizeofInternal(val.Field(i), true, depth)
        }

    case reflect.Array:
        if isNativeType(typ.Elem().Kind()) {
            break
        }
        sz = 0
        for i := 0; i < val.Len(); i++ {
            sz += sizeofInternal(val.Index(i), false, depth)
        }
    case reflect.Slice:
        if !fromStruct {
            sz = sliceSize
        }
        el := typ.Elem()
        if isNativeType(el.Kind()) {
            sz += uint64(val.Len()) * uint64(el.Size())
            break
        }
        for i := 0; i < val.Len(); i++ {
            sz += sizeofInternal(val.Index(i), false, depth)
        }
    case reflect.Map:
        if val.IsNil() {
            break
        }
        kel, vel := typ.Key(), typ.Elem()
        if isNativeType(kel.Kind()) && isNativeType(vel.Kind()) {
            sz += uint64(kel.Size()+vel.Size()) * uint64(val.Len())
            break
        }
        keys := val.MapKeys()
        for i := 0; i < len(keys); i++ {
            sz += sizeofInternal(keys[i], false, depth) + sizeofInternal(val.MapIndex(keys[i]), false, depth)
        }
    case reflect.String:
        if !fromStruct {
            sz = stringSize
        }
        sz += uint64(val.Len())
    }
    return
}

// Sizeof returns the estimated memory usage of object(s) not just the size of the type.
// On 64bit Sizeof("test") == 12 (8 = sizeof(StringHeader) + 4 bytes).
func Sizeof(objs ...interface{}) (sz uint64) {
    for i := range objs {
        sz += sizeofInternal(reflect.ValueOf(objs[i]), false, 0)
    }
    return
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/6oTOwVd9fS)

<strike>The math might be a tiny bit off.</strike>

// edit

Fixed the math and pushed to [github](https://github.com/OneOfOne/go-utils/tree/master/memory) for future references.

Comment: thanks @OneOfOne. this should be a most close solution to my knowledge.

Comment: @JasonXu if you improve it or enhance it, please drop me a link.

Comment: Maybe create a github repro for this and share it as a package? I see a lot of usecases that could benefit from this.

Comment: @OneOfOne Nice, now you are supposed to maintain it :)

Comment: @RickyA yeah that's fine, that repo have a bunch of random tiny functions I use on a daily bases, just didn't feel like splitting them into multiple repos. So it is maintained more or less.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit late but may be of help. The Sizeof() would return the size.

```
package util

import (
    "math/cmplx"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

var Size []uint64

//Sizeof Function Will Find Approximate Size of Object in Bytes
func Sizeof(i interface{}) (size uint64) {
    size = 0
    sizeof(reflect.ValueOf(i), &size)
    return
}

//sizeof  private function which used to calculate size of object
func sizeof(val reflect.Value, sizeptr *uint64) {
    if val.Kind() >= reflect.Bool && val.Kind() <= reflect.Complex128 {
        (*sizeptr) += Size[val.Kind()]
        return
    }
    switch val.Kind() {
    case reflect.String:
        (*sizeptr) += Size[reflect.String] * uint64(val.Len())
    case reflect.Array:
        /*
            Then iterate through the array and get recursively call the size method.
            If all element hold the same value calculate size for one and multiply it with
            length of array. Wont wonk correctly if the array holds slices or any dynamic
            elements
        */
        for i := 0; i < val.Len(); i++ {
            sizeof(val.Index(i), (sizeptr))
        }

    case reflect.Interface:
        /*
            First we need to get the underlying object of Interface in golang using the Elem()
            And then we need to recursively call this function
        */
        temp := val.Elem()
        sizeof(temp, (sizeptr))

    case reflect.Map:
        for _, key := range val.MapKeys() {
            /*
                get the size of key by calling the size function
            */
            sizeof(key, (sizeptr))

            /*
                get the value pointed by the key and then recursively compute its size
            */
            mapVal := val.MapIndex(key)
            sizeof(mapVal, sizeptr)
        }

    case reflect.Ptr:
        prtVal := val.Elem()
        /*
            If the pointer is invalid or the pointer is nil then return without updating the size
        */
        if !prtVal.IsValid() {
            return
        }

        sizeof(val.Elem(), sizeptr)

    case reflect.Slice:
        for i := 0; i < val.Len(); i++ {
            sizeof(val.Index(i), sizeptr)
        }

    case reflect.Struct:
        /*
            Didn't consider the NumMethod here. Don't this that this is necessary or is it??
            Need to verify this...
        */
        for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
            sizeof(val.Field(i), sizeptr)
        }

    case reflect.UnsafePointer:
        /*
            This allows conversion between elements. Dont think this should this is used in calculating
            size
        */
    case reflect.Func:
        // How to handle function pointers
    case reflect.Chan:
        // Don't think this case has to be handled as it will be produced and consumed
    default:
        return
    }
    return
}

func init() {
    Size = make([]uint64, 32)

    bool_val := true
    Size[reflect.Bool] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(bool(bool_val)))

    int_val := int(0)
    Size[reflect.Int] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(int_val))

    int8_val := int8(0)
    Size[reflect.Int8] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(int8_val))

    int16_val := int16(0)
    Size[reflect.Int16] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(int16_val))

    int32_val := int32(0)
    Size[reflect.Int32] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(int32_val))

    int64_val := int64(0)
    Size[reflect.Int64] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(int64_val))

    uint_val := uint(0)
    Size[reflect.Uint] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(uint_val))

    uint8_val := uint8(0)
    Size[reflect.Uint8] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(uint8_val))

    uint16_val := uint16(0)
    Size[reflect.Uint16] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(uint16_val))

    uint32_val := uint32(0)
    Size[reflect.Uint32] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(uint32_val))

    uint64_val := uint64(0)
    Size[reflect.Uint64] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(uint64_val))

    uintptr_val := uint64(0)
    Size[reflect.Uintptr] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(uintptr_val))

    float32_val := float32(0.0)
    Size[reflect.Float32] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(float32_val))

    float64_val := float64(0.0)
    Size[reflect.Float64] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(float64_val))

    complex64_val := complex64(cmplx.Sqrt(0 + 0i))
    Size[reflect.Complex64] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(complex64_val))

    complex128_val := complex128(cmplx.Sqrt(0 + 0i))
    Size[reflect.Complex128] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(complex128_val))

    string_val := string("0")
    Size[reflect.String] = uint64(unsafe.Sizeof(string_val))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if there's a difference between the two, but here's 
two ways, one using reflection and another using the unsafe package.

```
package main 
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

type T struct {
    a byte
    b int32
        c [1234]byte
        d float32   
}


func main(){
        var a T
    s1 := reflect.TypeOf(a)
    s2 := unsafe.Sizeof(T{})
    fmt.Printf("reflect.Sizeof(T) = %d, unsafe.Sizeof(T{} = %d)", s1.Size(), s2)
}
```

Comment: thanks @nos for fast replying. however one thing these way can't cover is "T{e:"ddddddddddddd",}" that an unfixed sized field in included. it has no affect the calculated size even super long.

Comment: True - but you already said "but without recursive reference" - that includes strings. Sizeof only gives you the size of the type. If a member is e.g. a pointer, the pointer counts towards the size, not what it points to. Same if there's a slice, only the slice type not the underlying array(if any), and only the string type, not the content of the string - a string is pretty much like a slice. If you have slice/pointer/string/map/channel members, you'd have to recurse down the list of members of the struct and e.g. also find the length of those - that can be done with reflection.

Comment: sorry @nos for my being not clear. "recursive" means there's no pointer pointing back to self or any child.. :)